# Как сделать в FastReport тихий экспорт в Excel?

Tags: delphi, excel, fastreport

Как сделать в FastReport экспорт в Excel в т.ч. без показа диалогов и без разрывов страниц? Приведите пожалуйста полный пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
frReport1.ShowProgress := false;
if frRepor1.PrepareReport then
  frReport1.ExportTo(frXLSExport1, FileName);
```

Где frXLSExport1 - имя компонента для экспорта с закладки Fastreport Exports, который вы кинули на форму, FileName - имя файла, в который хотите сохранить.

Может отличаться для разных версий Дельфи и FastReport.

Comment: Все равно вылезает маленькое окошко с параметрами экспорта (неразрывные страницы или с разрвами и т.п.)

Comment: @Merlin для frXLSExport1 следует добавить 
  frxXLSExport1.ShowDialog := false;